# how to get the list of Eventbrite groups in a given city using Eventbrite's API

Tags: ruby, eventbrite

These are the current API methods they have:

API methods:

```
**Events**
event_search
event_get
event_new
event_copy
event_update

**Organizer Profiles**
organizer_list_events
organizer_get
organizer_new
organizer_update
```

For more: http://developer.eventbrite.com/doc/

I want get the information about groups in a specified city or zip code but the API is very limited. The Meetup.com website for example allows you to fetch meetup groups by zip code. Is there a way to do that in Eventbrite, has anyone had any experience with their API.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Start with Eventbrite's [event_search](http://developer.eventbrite.com/doc/events/event_search/) API method.  It should provide access to all of their publicly available event data.  You can filter this request by location (zip codes supported).

Each event object that is returned from the API should have an attached 'organizer' entity.  The [Organizer Profile Pages](http://developer.eventbrite.com/doc/organizers/) allow event hosts to showcase their activity and their list of upcoming events - They are probably what you are looking for.